# Changing the value of a global variable in a .js file

Tags: javascript, global, local

it doesnt change to false!! please help 
i need to change the value of Password to false

```
//password check
{

 connection.connect(function(){
    connection.query('select * from rencho2.user',function(err,results){ 
        if(results[0].passwd==p){
            console.log("correct");
        else { 
               global.verify="false";
           console.log("Incorrect. "); //here its false                             
        }                                 
         //here its false
   }); 
                //here it becomes true -- why??

    send = { 
        "UserName": body.UserName,
        "Password": global.verify
    }
    body1=JSON.stringify(send);
});

});
```

Comment: Not the bees! My eyes! Not the bees!!

Comment: Please provide your entire implementation. Where is this verify variable being declared?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Your anonymous function is probably getting called after you create the send object

Comment: This is the 3rd such question I have seen where the developer is completely oblivious to this characteristic of async code the last few days.

Comment: @dwerner This class of question gets asked several times per day. Vote to close a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call and move on.

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with asynchronous and synchronous code. `connection.query` executes *after* the outer code is done. It is only at that point, `global.verify` is `false`. Prior to that `global.verify` is `true` because the callback to `connection.query` has not executed yet. You should do what you need from within the callback:

```
connection.query('select * from rencho2.user',function(err,results){ 
    if(results[0].passwd==p) {
        console.log("correct");
    } else { 
        global.verify="false";
        console.log("Incorrect. "); //here its false                             
    }                                 

    send = { 
        "UserName": body.UserName,
        "Password": global.verify
    };

    body1 = JSON.stringify(send);

    //do what you need with body1  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems strange, and with no context it's a hard question to answer, but generally asynchronous behaviour is a good thing, but if for some strange reason you really need it to be synchronous you can always fake it :

```
connection.connect(function(){
    var done = false;

    connection.query('select * from rencho2.user', function(err,results) { 
        if(results[0].passwd == p){
            console.log("correct");
        } else { 
            global.verify = false;
            console.log("Incorrect. ");
        }
        done = true;
    }); 

    while (done == false) {};

    send = { 
        "UserName": body.UserName,
        "Password": global.verify
    }
    body1 = JSON.stringify(send);
});
```

note: this is generally not a good idea, but will work as a last resort !